# android app crashes when a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, xml, android-location

I made an app and a part of the app is to get the longitude and latitude add these into one string and use that string to get an xml file from the weather servers so you can see what weather, temperature, humidity... it is at your place.

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/instruction_nexttobutton_english" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="getPositionAndGetWheater"
    android:text="@string/getweather_button_english" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.thelexapp;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void getPositionAndGetWheater(View view) {
    LocationManager lm =                 (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    String longitudestring = String.valueOf(longitude);
    String latitudestring = String.valueOf(latitude);
    String URLforweather =     "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=" + longitudestring + "," + latitudestring + "&format=xml&num_of_days=1&key=IHAVEAAPIKEYBUTI'MNOTPOSTINGITONTHEFORUMFORSECURITYREASONS";
    WebView webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview); 
    webview.loadUrl(URLforweather);

}


}
```

"appname" Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.thelexapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.thelexapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

LOGCAT WINDOWS:

```
02-26 15:00:26.710: D/dalvikvm(977): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-26 15:00:29.730: V/WebViewChromium(977): Binding Chromium to the background looperLooper{b1dceb80}
02-26 15:00:29.750: I/chromium(977): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium     logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
02-26 15:00:29.770: I/BrowserProcessMain(977): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
02-26 15:00:29.960: E/chromium(977): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
02-26 15:00:29.960: E/chromium(977): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
02-26 15:00:29.960: E/chromium(977): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
02-26 15:00:29.960: E/chromium(977): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
02-26 15:00:29.970: E/chromium(977): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
02-26 15:00:30.000: W/chromium(977): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
02-26 15:00:30.150: D/dalvikvm(977): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 88K, 5% free 3235K/3392K, paused 48ms, total 50ms
02-26 15:00:30.160: I/dalvikvm-heap(977): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.297MB for 1127536-byte allocation
02-26 15:00:30.230: D/dalvikvm(977): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 4333K/4496K, paused 67ms, total 67ms
02-26 15:00:30.800: D/gralloc_goldfish(977): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-26 15:00:30.880: W/AwContents(977): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
02-26 15:00:31.870: W/AwContents(977): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
02-26 15:00:31.930: W/AwContents(977): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
02-26 15:00:32.000: W/AwContents(977): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
02-26 15:00:32.020: W/AwContents(977): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
02-26 15:00:32.090: W/AwContents(977): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
02-26 15:00:32.130: W/AwContents(977): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
02-26 15:00:31.817: D/AndroidRuntime(977): Shutting down VM
02-26 15:00:31.817: W/dalvikvm(977): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1af5b90)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977): Process: com.example.thelexapp, PID: 977
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  ... 11 more
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.example.thelexapp.MainActivity.getPositionAndGetWheater(MainActivity.java:33)
02-26 15:00:31.827: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  ... 14 more
02-26 15:00:37.167: I/Process(977): Sending signal. PID: 977 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace please. And be aware that `getLastKnownLocation` can return `null`.

Comment: You haven't called the onClick at all, unless I'm blind. Sorry just saw it.

Comment: @RED_ It is defined in the xml file.

Comment: what's a stacktrace? xD thanks for the help :)

Comment: Post the error message from the LogCat Window ;)

Comment: how would i solve the problem that it may return null? thanks ;)

Comment: logcat window coming ;) wait a second plz ;) thx everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you testing it on emulator or device? There is a posibility that your `Location location` is null. Please make sure you have corresponding permission in your manifest. To handle such situations, you should check your location for `null`:

```
public void getPositionAndGetWheater(View view) {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {

        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        String longitudestring = String.valueOf(longitude);
        String latitudestring = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String URLforweather = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=" + longitudestring + "," + latitudestring + "&format=xml&num_of_days=1&key=IHAVEAAPIKEYBUTI'MNOTPOSTINGITONTHEFORUMFORSECURITYREASONS";
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.loadUrl(URLforweather);
    } else {
        //show error
    }

}
```

Comment: it works but the button doesn't display anything, that's probly because i tested it with the security api, i'l try it with the coorect api key and if it still doesn't work it is probably executing the else statemtn thank you very much ;) i want to arrow up this comment but i need reputation 15 :s **thank you very much**

Comment: yup, it is returining null, i'l try it on a real phone but i need to go right now thanky ou very much ;)